# Is there a term for ordering items by color by wave length?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I tried looking for the word "chromologically", but didn't find any evidence to its existence.

Further answers about sorting not by wave length, but by other factors, such as saturation, or brightness, are also welcome.

Comment: Using Latin rather than Greek, one gets "colour sequence".

Comment: I know of no natural order of colours other than by wavelength, i.e. as in the colour spectrum. Is this what you mean? If so, I imagine you could make an adverb or adjective from spectrum — but I wouldn't, myself.

Comment: @David Yes, that's what I meant in this case, but if there's a term for ordering generally by color even by different logic, I'd like to know.

Comment: Well I'm not a colour scientist (or even an artist), but from my encounter with graphics software I am aware that you can order colours on different properties like hue and brightness. This Wikipedia article on [colour theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory) may be of interest.

Comment: The adverb 'chromatically' exists, but 'chromatical' has the broad meaning 'relating to colour' and would sound distinctly odd in the sense you mean. 'According to wavelength' sounds more natural. // Of course, ordering items using a colour highlighting-technique is _colour coding_.

Comment: In shops (especially charity shops) where everything of one colour is placed together, it's called "colour blocking"

Comment: Did you mean to *order* things in a specific, reproducible color order? (Then I'd agree with @David that I only know of a wavelength order that you can see in a rainbow, going by the mnemonic ROYGBIV.) Or did you mean instead to *group* things by color?

Comment: @rajah9 To order them by wavelength, or other color property like saturation

Comment: **Please edit your question to explain what ordering items “by their color” means**, and why that phrase won’t work. Why can’t you just say ***“by color”*** (whatever that means) and leave it at that? Why one word? What do you need just one nonspaced term for? Presumably you want some “manner adverb” (a word like *easily, quickly, alphabetically, righteously, preferentially* that’s been derived from some ᴀᴅᴊᴇᴄᴛɪᴠᴇ + *-ly* to mean “in an ᴀᴅᴊᴇᴄᴛɪᴠᴇ manner”) for something we would almost always use a multiword prepositional phrase or clause for, like *by cost* or *by name* or *by price*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there any many ways to order color, there’s no specific name for “sorting by color”.

See: [*The incredibly challenging task of sorting colours*](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/30/colour-sorting/)

Sometimes, you will say things are in “[*rainbow order*](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-order-colors-rainbow-289367)”, which is the sorted band of sunlight colors, by wavelength, as passing through a prism. This is only a subset of possible colors.

See also: [*How to sort colors properly?*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87588/how-to-sort-colors-properly)

> You can’t sort colors. Because the human eye has three distinct color
>   sensors (red, green, and blue), color is fundamentally a
>   three-dimensional quantity, and there is no linear ordering that
>   brings together “similar” colors. If you sort first by the amount of
>   red, for example, then you may bring together wildly different hues
>   and brightnesses. If you sort by hue, then you bring together wildly
>   different degrees of saturation and brightness, and so on. There’s
>   just no way to do it.

Comment: ***Spectral*** “colors” are trivially orderable by wavelength: monochromatic “red” of say 700 nm has a single scalar numeric value distinct from that of monochromatic “violet” of say 400 nm. But that will get you nowhere for the infinitely many ***non-spectral*** “colors”—such as purple or pink, beige or brown, or black, white, or grey—as these all lack a *monochromatic metamere* to use for wavelength ordering. As you note, *non-spectral* colors combine two or more *spectral* colors (read: *monochromatic wavelengths of light*) into the *tristimulus value* the human mind needs to perceive them.